# How to remove comma and make it as normal array with PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem with array conversion , I have try to use explode function to extract text from database as an array. Unfortunately the result was not match of my expectation.

```
$string = "A,B";
```

This is what I have tried :

```
print_r(explode(',',$string);
```

Result :

```
 array([0]=>A,[1]=>B);
```

**My result should be :**

```
 array(A,B);
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: This is the correct output, every array value has an unique key.

Comment: How should I do with that?

Comment: `array([0]=>A,[1]=>B);` **is** `array(A,B);`. Can you `print_r()` the value that you get, then `print_r()` the value that you would like to get, and post the `print_r()` output of both?

Comment: `array([0]=>A,[1]=>B);` and `array(A,B);` are the same it is only `print_r` shows you the indxes of your array

Comment: I want to use the array which I have tried to select from database to compare with other key words by using in_array function. But the array([0]=>A,[1]=>B) was not good for me, so may be the second one is the best array(A,B).

Comment: yes, Please wait for a while.

Comment: example: `$Myarray =array(0=>"A",1=>"B");
if(in_array("A",$Myarray)){
 print "Key exists";
}` --> works output `Key exists`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `explode(',',$string)` is already an array, `print_r` just should show you the array structure.

With your comment, `in_array` just works like:

```
if (in_array('A', explode(',',$string))) {
  //..
}
```

And further more, if you save data like `A,B` in your mysql db, and want to check whether `A` exists in it, you could use `FIND_IN_SET` function.

```
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
        -> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
print_r(explode(',',$string);
```

to

```
print_r(explode(',',$string));
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you did not make a typo in your code? The sample you give should always output the following:

```
Array ( [0] => A [1] => B )
```

If it does not explode on the comma delimiter (since A, with a comma is part of the result of explode.. then you probably have a mistake.

You also miss a ')' on

```
print_r(explode(',',$string);
```

So like this

```
print_r(explode(',',$string));
```